# Exim version 4.72 silently drops mail sent to user beginning with plus sign

Tags: exim

Exim 4.72 accepts emails for recipients of format "0123456@domain.my", and forwards these to our smarthost. Smarthost accepts the messages, they reach the recipient, and all this is shown in the log.

But, adding a plus sign to the address (as in "+0123456@domain.my") causes the mail to be silently lost, even though the mail command seems to accept it. There are no rows in the exim logs (mainlog, rejectlog; on debian) related to the lost emails.

Exim 4.89 on another host happily passes messages with +recipient on to the smarthost.

Is there a configuration setting affecting to what recipient addresses are accepted/rejected? Or is this purely a version issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` and `-` are the default value for the `local_part_suffix` option. When this option is set, incoming mails for `user+foo@example.com` will be handled as `user@example.com`, the `foo` part will be stripped from the address for mail handling.

From [the documentation](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_default_configuration_file.html):

> The two commented options that follow check_local_user, namely:
>
> ```
> # local_part_suffix = +* : -*
> # local_part_suffix_optional
> ```
>
> show how you can specify the recognition of local part suffixes. If the first is uncommented, a suffix beginning with either a plus or a minus sign, followed by any sequence of characters, is removed from the local part and placed in the variable $local_part_suffix. The second suffix option specifies that the presence of a suffix in the local part is optional. When a suffix is present, the check for a local login uses the local part with the suffix removed.

In your case, with nothing before the `+`, there is no user left to whom the mail could be delivered.

You can change the option to a different character.

Comment: Thank you Gerald! I tested local delivery with a user+anystring, and, indeed, mail was delivered to user. My configuration does not have explicit setting of local_part_suffix, so I still need to figure out how to add it, using the update-exim4.conf / split configuration. But that is another question... this one is solved! Thanks for speedy answer!

Comment: Just in case anyone else has the same problem: the special function of + sign in local addresses can be eliminated with setting `local_part_suffix = unset` in the router for local mail.

Comment: @mvuot, any luck with custom settings into Debian-config-based Exim4?